# MySql Query question last time record found in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
  SELECT device, COUNT(*) 
    FROM database.table 
GROUP BY device 
  HAVING count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY device;
```

What I need to do is add a column that shows the last time the device connected to the database.

The table is structured like:

```
ID, device(string),
data1(int),data2(int), 
time(timestamp), 
data3(int),
data4(int)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  select device, count(*) as cnt, max(time) <-- same as latest time
    from database.table 
group by device
  having cnt>1
order by device;
```